# How to handle conditions when using mustache.js

Tags: javascript, mustache

Suppose I have a list of items each one with a property (`status`) which can have one of these values:

- 0 (inactive)
- 1 (queued)
- 2 (active)

I need to display three different things in the template according to that value. These three things differ in markup and not only value.

Now mustache being logic-less doesn't really provide logic constructs. Only boolean conditions can be "emulated ifs" with sections and inverted sections.

Given that I have 3 different status values, what's the best way to construct the template?

1. I can add three separate boolean properties and use sections
2. I can cycle on all the items before rendering and add another property to each item containing the correct markup imported by another template (seems a bit overkill)
3. other?

Answer (score 2):

Use [Handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/) if you want to add logic to logic-less Mustache